# Install linux on server

Tags: php, linux, apache, webserver

I have a desktop and I want to install linux on it and use it as a server. I believe I dont need to install a complete linux distro cause I dont need the user interface, I can command the server using ssh in another computer and tell my web server to install apache, mysql...

I want my webserver not to consume CPU with GUI or mouse or keyboard... I want my linux distro to only usage the resources needed to run the webserver.

Before you ask why I want to do this I will explain myself: I am using AWS for some time and it's amazing how they provide a cloud where I install a linux image and I can control it using SSH from my home! Their server is probably not running any interface, probably there is not even a screen there. It's just a CPU running my web server and listening to SSH to do as I say. There is no need to consume resources having a linux distro with gui and listening to keyboard and mouse events!

Comment: Seems to be off-topic although it's hard to be sure as there's not actually a question...

Comment: my question is where do I download a linux with no gui? where do I download iso images that AWS use for linux? I have no idea how to search it on google

Comment: Most linux flavours offer a server version, just go to the sites of Ubuntu, Fedora, SuSe, etc. Or use a normal version and don't install a graphic environment.

Comment: I suspect this would be a better question for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)  Try the LTS release.  Should have SSH, Apache, MySQL and PHP ready to roll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many linux distributions do not require you to install a GUI.  Debian and Ubuntu both have this capability to name just a couple.  If you install Ubuntu's server version, or uncheck the Desktop environment and check SSH Server in Debian, you'll be able to manage your Linux server like you're managing your AWS instance.

You need linux installed or running off a live CD if you're going to use it as a server.  If you don't want to overwrite your desktop installation, you could always use a virtual machine.   [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) is a good virtualization software for Windows.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that during the installation I could avoid the GUI instalation! :)